# not serializable exception while trying to writeObject from an array

Tags: java, exception

I am getting a NotSerializableException while running an application file trying to write an object to a .dat file.

```
    try{
        Person[] personList = new Person[3];
        personList[0] = new TeamLeader(8, "Mike Johnson", 29);
        personList[1] = new Engineer(0.4,"Russell Sanders", 22);
        personList[2] = new Engineer(0.7, "Steven Peterson", 25);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("persons.dat"));
        for(int i = 0; i < personList.length; i++) {
            out.writeObject(personList[i]);//error line 85
        }
        //out.writeObject(personList);
    }

    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem writing file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

error

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: TeamLeader
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java: 346)
     at CharlieBrownP6.main(CharlieBrownP6.java: 85)
```

error goes on to about writing aborted for the same error

Comment: Do `Person`, `TeamLeader`, and `Engineer` implement `Serializable`?  If they don't, then that's your problem - all objects that you serialize need to implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects calling writeObject must implement the `Serializable` interface ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)).

Comment: For some reason it was escaping me that Serializable was an interface, once i realized that it made alot more sense. Thanks again stack overflow solved my error